# Bareリポジトリのgit fetchができない

Tags: centos, git, redmine, gitlab

### 困っていること

RedmineとGitLabを連携して運用しています。
Redmine上でgit管理しているプロジェクトの更新履歴を参照しています。

数日前にRedmineを構成しているサーバ上の、Bareリポジトリでコマンド
`git fetch origin master`
が通らなくなりました。
コマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

OS
　Redmine ：CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
　GitLab ：CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

git管理しているプロジェクト名をprojectとしますと、
Redmineを構成するサーバ上のBareリポジトリディレクトリproject.git内の
configファイルは以下の内容です。

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
    url = git@example.com:project/project_document.git
```

### 確認内容・その他

以前はこの状態でコマンドが通っていました。
URLを `http://{gitユーザ名}@example.com:{ポート番号}/project/project_document.git`
とすれば、パスワード入力を促され、入力することで実行できます。
しかし、以前の設定内容では、パスワードを入力することなく実行できていました。
Bareリポジトリディレクトリおよびディレクトリ下のファイル所有者をrootから
変更したことが原因として思い当たりますが、変更後にも１度fetchできていました。
また、１度所有者をrootに戻して再度実行してみましたが、同様のエラーでした。

fatal: ～のエラーについて調べ、
`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
とコマンドを入力してconfigファイルを変更してみても実行できませんでした。
そもそもfetchしたい対象ファイルの容量はあまり大きくないはずなので、
このようなエラー内容が表示される原因もよくわかっていません。
何かご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。
GitLabの設定不備が原因でした。
目を通していただいた方々、申し訳ありませんでした。
編集していただいた方々は、ありがとうございました。

【解決方法】
GitLabのWebブラウザ上で/project/project_documentリポジトリの
Settings→Repositoryを開き、Deploy KeysのうちredmineをEnabledに変更する。
お時間いただき大変申し訳ございませんでした。